# I have a little complex model, about EF cascade delete

Tags: entity-framework, cascade

Code first,and model look like this Figure:

[image]

```
public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public int fid { get; set; }
    public int uid { get; set; }
    public virtual lnk lnk { get; set; }
    public virtual user user { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<img> imgs { get; set; }
}

public class lnk 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string lnkman { get; set; }
}

public class model1:Post
{
    public string content { get; set; }
}

public class user
{
    public int uid { get;set; }
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Post> posts { get; set; }
}

public class img
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string imgUrl { get; set; }
    public int pid { get; set; }
    public virtual Post post { get; set; }
}

public class PostContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Post> posts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<user> users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<img> imgs { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Post>().HasKey(i=>i.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<lnk>().HasKey(i => i.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Post>().HasRequired(i => i.lnk).WithRequiredPrincipal();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Post>().ToTable("Post");
        modelBuilder.Entity<lnk>().ToTable("Post");

        modelBuilder.Entity<model1>().ToTable("model1");

        modelBuilder.Entity<user>().HasKey(i => i.uid).ToTable("user");

        modelBuilder.Entity<user>().HasMany(i => i.posts)
                                  .WithRequired(i => i.user)
                                  .HasForeignKey(i =>i.uid).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<img>().HasKey(i => i.id).ToTable("img");

        modelBuilder.Entity<Post>().HasMany(i => i.imgs)
                                   .WithRequired(i => i.post)
                                   .HasForeignKey(i => i.pid)
                                   .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

the add and list method work well. but delele like this :

```
using (var db = new PostContext())
{
    //model1 ToDel = new model1{ Id=id };
    //b.Entry(ToDel).State = System.Data.EntityState.Deleted;
    var ToDel = db.users.Single(i => i.uid == id);

    db.users.Remove(ToDel);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return id + "DE: well done!" ;
}
```

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: DELETE statement with REFERENCE constraint   "FK_dbo.Post_dbo.user_uid" conflict。The conflict occurred in database "jefunfl"，table "dbo.Post", column 'uid'

I want delete users with user's posts, and posts with post's imgs.
How can I do this? Can some one give any tips?

btw,my Chinese English may be funny. forgive me.
this is my first post,but I am not new guy.  thanks

Comment: Did you enable cascade delete on the relationship between your tables?

Comment: You use WillCascadeOnDelete( **false** ). MSDN: true if cascade delete is on; otherwise, false.

Comment: Could you add an answer to your question and move the text below `ADD this` into it? (So remove it from your post).

Answer (score 0):

bypass all one day, i found it.  and thank you for answer to me.

1:
i delete WillCascadeOnDelete() method,so let ef do it by Conventions.

2:
i found that ,when i delete the posts,i can't  directly delete with this statement like ToDel = db.posts.Single(i => i.Id == id)
but this:
ToDel = db.posts.Include(i=>i.lnk).Single(i => i.Id == id)
post and lnk  has a relatialship that is called table splitting.  both mapping to the same post table. when delete posts, EF can auto delete post.imgs by conventions. what will happen when delete user ? and so i got it. my code blow:

```
            var ToDel = db.users.Include(i => i.posts)
                                .Single(i => i.uid == id);
            var PostToDel = db.posts.Include(i => i.lnk)
                              .Single(i => i.Id == ToDel.uid);
            db.posts.Remove(PostToDel);
            db.users.Remove(ToDel);
            db.SaveChanges();
```

this will work well. even not perfectly. but it  can do what i want without a exception.

at last,the biggest problem is post class and lnk class has a "table splitting".
when delete post we should  explicitly include.

i dont know if you can understand me, my english is very ugly. i am foolish with courage.
thank u. i am happy